# Updating libpng in Android Studio (Buildbox Project) to fix Vulnerability

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, libpng

My android game has been rejected because it contains **Libpng** Vulnerability. the game created from Buildbox, and i don't have the buildbox project files. i just have Android Studio project files.
It has only

```
src/main/jniLibs
```

which has **/x86** & **/armeabi** & **/armeabi-v7a** with **libplayer.so** files.

I am also using **Dagger** & **Javax-inject** & **Nineoldandroids** Libraries

**How can i know which library is using it and how to upgrade to a newer version of libpng.**

I am working on windows by the way.

this is the message that i got from google play

> "This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as
>   soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>
> Vulnerability APK Version(s) Libpng library The vulnerabilities were
>   fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher. You
>   can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google
>   Help Center article. "

I tried all the solutions i could find but nothing helped me.

Comment: please guys i need help

Comment: I'm also interested, did you find a solution?

Comment: Still no solution

Comment: hi did you find solution now ?